# Interpolate @yield() value within {{}} or the asset() helper in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to interpolate a `@yield('page-name')` value in the `asset()` helper method:

I **think** that blade directives cannot be used with php (I mean within `{{}}`)

This is what I'm trying to do:

```html
//guest.blade.php file
<html>
   <head>
      <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }} - @yield('title')</title>

     // this throws an error
     // ParseError: syntax error, unexpected token "<"
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/'. @yield('view-asset') .'.css') }}">
   </head>
   <body>
      @yield('content')
   </body>
</html>

//login.blade.php file
@extends('layouts.guest')

@section('title', 'Login-page')
@section('view-asset')

@section('content')
   ...
@endsection
```

How can do a similar implementation, to what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: I think you cannot do what you want to do, as you are saying, you cannot mix PHP with Blade (not in the middle of PHP). So you should pass what string you want from the controller, but that is not exactly good, because the controller now has the responsibility of getting and setting the desired PATH. I would share more code so we understand why you need `@yield(...)` in there

Comment: @matiaslauriti All the views have 2 stylesheets and 2 js files,  where one of each is named after the view-name:  `global.css`, `[view-name].css`, `global.js` and `[view-name].js`... so I am trying to avoid the situation where I have to use `@section('stylesheet', '<link src="{{asset('css/view-name.css') />}})` and `@section('javacript', '<link src="{{asset('js/view-name.css') />}})` on every view

Comment: if you pass the value you want from the controller to the view, you can do `asset("css/{$view_asset_name}.css")`

Comment: `@yield(x)` is blade shorthand for PHP code `$__env->yieldContent(x)` in case that can work for you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `view()` helper function.

`Illuminate\View\View` namespace holds `Illuminate\View\Factory` in it which contains data like files, paths, hints, views, section, etc.

To get yield data (retrieved from section directive of child view), In your parent view:

```
view('your.view')->getFactory()->getSection('page-name');
```

You can also pass a default value for the section.

```
view('your.view')->getFactory()->getSection('page-name' , 'default value');
```

Which in your case it would be like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/'.view("directory.guest")->getFactory()->getSection("page-name" , "default_value").'.css') }}">
```